# Disable Link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I disable a link in jQuery? Previously I was changing the anchor's href attribute but realized this would not be the best way to stop the user being taken to a new page. I added disabled true to the attribute instead but this isn't working. The click still needs to work - I just don't want the link in the anchor to activate.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-nav");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active-hit");
    this.find('a').attr('disabled', true);
    //this.find("a").attr("href", "#");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: links don't have a disabled attribute, question has been asked a bunch of times before.

Comment: What do you mean by "The click still needs to work - I just don't want the link in the anchor to activate."?

Comment: I need to retain the link for desktop view. I'm disabling for an accordion on mobile.

Comment: So why not just remove the menu on mobile with CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event (`e`) parameter to the click function and the use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the link from being followed.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-nav");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("active-hit");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Updated jQuery Solution following on from comments:**

```js
var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-nav > a');

$dropdown.on('click', function(e){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active-hit'); 
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changing to a JQuery function like so doesn't seem to work. $dropdown.click(function(e) {
              $(this).toggleClass('active-hit');
              //$(this).find('a').attr('disabled', true);
              e.preventDefault();
            });

Comment: it is the list item .dropdown-nav

Comment: Ok trying this out it doesn't allow me to click on the list item (to open the accordion). Are we able to apply the e.preventDefault() to just the anchor which is a child of the list item?

Comment: That seems to work - the accordion opens. However the links within (.secon-tier) cannot be followed - they are disabled like the child of the drop-down parent.

Comment: Changing `$('.dropdown-nav a')` to `$('.dropdown-nav > a')` should solve it. Answer updated too.

Comment: Ah yes - so similar to CSS in selecting adjacent element. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the 'on'

```js
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('default link action prevented');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `pointer-events: none;` css property to the element you want to not be clicked. It makes it just as not visible to your pointer.

Then just use `js` to toggle this class as you need.

```css
.noClickAllowed {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown-nav noClickAllowed">
    <a href="/about">About
      <span class="nav-desc">Our company</span>
    </a>
    <div class="hide-border"></div>
    <ul class="second-tier">
      <div class="hide-corner"></div>
      <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">High Value Manufacturing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```